# Where to put Data Contracts WCF? Ok to put in Data Layer?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I've see a few people recommend that a WCF service call the data layer, have an object containing data returned, and then putting that into a data contract. My question is why not stick the data contracts in the data layer itself and just return them instead? Is there a disadvantage to doing that? Reason I ask is that my data layer is just a class library and I want to be able to call it from multiple platforms that may not be using the webservice. I can't seem to find a best practice regarding this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disadvantage of putting your contracts in your datalayer is that you're coupling your datalayer to your service contracts, when in fact they don't need to be concerned with eachother. Ideally, your datalayer should be responsible for just doing what it says on the tin. What you might be looking for are [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (DTO's). They're meant to just transfer data to your clients. In your servicelayer you can convert these back to their respective entities for doing whatever needs doing. This does create overhead however and you'll need a way to map DTO's and entities back and forth, for example with [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. Feels redundant though creating two objects that essentially do the same thing.

Comment: They may look the same, but they don't do the same thing. The DTO's do just one thing, transport data. They're 'dumb', they should not contain any behavior, because they're only used to transport data to your presentation layer. Your entities (or POCO's perhaps) typically describe how your domain model looks. And AutoMapper makes it really easy to accomplish this, so that's one worry less.

Comment: Not to talk it to death... but wouldn't you say DataContracts have no behavior and are only used to store data? Wouldn't this make them a DTO? So essentially you are saying the fact that I'm returning a type defined in my DAL is the coupling problem? So you define all your data contracts in the same layer as your service layer?

Comment: Your DAL could not mean anything to whomever may be consuming your services. If you're returning an entity from your DAL from your service, you're coupling your clients to your DAL. And all changes to that DAL will be reflected on your clients. If you decouple them, you won't have these problems. I'd define the contracts in the service layer, because what a service does is described by the contract.